# Using Source Command From A Python Script

Tags: python, unix, subprocess

I was tring to call the source command in unix from a python script. I was trying to get it done with subprocess.Popen passing the os environment to it.

Below is my function for doing the task of executing a command:

```
def run_command(command, tst_env):
    print tst_env
    try:
       p = subprocess.Popen(command, env=tst_env, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
       stout, er = p.communicate()
       print stout, er
       ret = p.wait()
    except Exception, e:
       print "Exception: ", e
    else :
        if ret:
          print command, "failed", ret
          return
        else:
          print command, "succeeded", ret
    return p
```

The `tst_env` is an object of os.environ type.

`run_command(source script.sh, os.environ)` says it is successful.

But I am not able to access the functions in the script.

The case is like this:

script.sh follows:

```
function task_test() {
   echo "Test function called"
}

source script.sh
```

`task_test` will call the function in the shell script.

But I am not able to call the functions in the shell script from python.

Hope I am clear.

Comment: can you elaborate, what you can't access.. and from where

Comment: Please [learn to use MarkDown](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for the next question! :)

Comment: What do stout and er say?  And what should they say if the shell script ran successfully?  You don't need a `p.wait()` - `p.communicate()` does not return until the subprocess exits.

Comment: p.wait() is for making the script wait to get an indication of the success while running the script. And p.communicate is used to get the stdout messages. What I want is to use the functions in the shell script we write.  If from within the shell we could use the source command. But I am not able to get it done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`subprocess` is there for executing things. It doesn't give you a bridge between shell functions and Python. You can't "load" a shell file and then treat it as a Python object you can call. You can just execute the contents of the script.

Comment: @GeorgeThomas: not practically, but you can write something which will execute a given function, by executing this sort of `source file.sh; [function]` thing.